# Is it possible to Skip Blank Lines in a Dataframe? If Yes then how I can do this

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to run this code

```
num = df_out.drop_duplicates(subset=['Name', 'No.']).groupby.(['Name']).size()
```

But when I do I get this error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

If we think about my dataframe(df_out) as an excel file I do have blank cells but no full column or full row is blank. I needed to skip the blank lines to run the code without changing the dataframe's structure.

Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: `df_out.drop_duplicates(subset=['Name', 'No.']).groupby(['Name']).size()` no dot after grouby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using `df.dropna()`. It is uses to remove rows that contains NA. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html for more information.

At first, you probably want your "blank cells" to be converted to NA value, so they can be dropped by `dropna()`. This can be done using various methods, notably `df.replace(r'\s+', pandas.np.nan, regex=True)`. If your "blank cells" are all empty strings, or fixed strings equal to some value `s`, you can directly use (first case) `df.replace('', pandas.np.nan)` or (second case) `df.replace(s, pandas.np.nan)`.

Comment: Thank you. I had a quick question about that. Is there any way do drop just the cells with NA and not the entire row/column?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But some operations in pandas can take NA into account and simply "skip" them (e.g. `df.mean()`). Most of the time, these operations accept a `skipna` parameter that defaults to `True`.